# On typing dev/usb/lp0 it says 'no such file or directory'

Tags: printing

i am trying to use escputil to determine ink level.On typing `dev/usb/lp0` it says *'no such file or directory'*.

Comment: note that the path is likely to be `/dev/usb/lp0`, not `dev/usb/lp0` - and typing it alone doesn't make much sense. Please provide the full command you're entering

Answer (score 0):

Try using **SUDO** . The **MAN** page for **escputil** also says this error as a known bug, try retyping the command once again that should resolve the issue.

```
   USB-connected printers sometimes fail to identify or return ink levels.
   You may have to repeat the command.  This is probably a timing issue in
   escputil, not a flaw in the printer.

   Anything  requiring bidirectional communication with the printer (iden-
   tify, ink levels, or head  alignment  without  specifying  the  printer
   model)  requires  read/write  access  to  the printer port (for example
   /dev/lp0).  This may require these operations to be performed as  root.
   In  addition,  kernel  support is required for bidirectional communica-
   tion.   For  Linux  version  2.2,  CONFIG_PRINTER_READBACK  should   be
   enabled; this is called CONFIG_PARPORT_1284 on 2.4 and later kernels.

   If  the  printer  is performing self-test or head cleaning on power up,
   the identify and ink level commands will time out, although the printer
   successfully  receives  the command.  The command will need to be reis-
   sued when the printer is quiescent.
```

Comment: Same error with sudo.